# Replicating chmod's symbolic mode in Ruby without explicitly invoking a system command

Tags: ruby, chmod

On Unix/Linux systems, the `chmod` function supports "symbolic modes", meaning you can do what is essentially bit-arithmetic with permissions, e.g. `chmod u+x ...` is a symbolic form for adding executable permissions for the user.  The `chmod` function in Ruby's `FileUtils` only supports an absolute bitmask as a permission, i.e. you can only do `FileUtils.chmod(0777, ...)` but `FileUtils.chmod('u+x', ...)` will not work.

I get that one way to do this is to just call the `system` command directly: `system("chmod u+x ...")`, but I'd prefer to keep code in the Ruby domain as much as possible without spawning shells everywhere.  Alternatively, I could iterate through `File` objects, `File.stat` them, get their existing bitmasks and modify them individually, but symbolic modes will support a file glob, which is much more succinct and less error prone.

Does anyone know whether there is a way to do this in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Ruby are you using? Look at the [1.9.3 docs for FileUtils.chmod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod):

> Changes permission bits on the named files (in list) to the bit
>       pattern represented by mode. mode is the symbolic and absolute mode
>       can be used. Absolute mode is
>
> ```
> FileUtils.chmod 0755, 'somecommand'
> FileUtils.chmod 0644, %w(my.rb your.rb his.rb her.rb)
> FileUtils.chmod 0755, '/usr/bin/ruby', :verbose => true
> ```
>
> Symbolic mode is
>
> ```
> FileUtils.chmod "u=wrx,go=rx", 'somecommand'
> FileUtils.chmod "u=wr,go=rr", %w(my.rb your.rb his.rb her.rb)
> FileUtils.chmod "u=wrx,go=rx", '/usr/bin/ruby', :verbose => true
> ```

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.8.7, so I guess that functionality is not available to me yet.

Comment: Is there anything specific that keeps you from updating? With RVM or rbenv it's rather hassle free to install alternative Ruby versions and switch on a per app basis.

Comment: Our current production systems are stuck on Ubuntu Lucid, which is still on 1.8 (actually even the most recent version, Oneiric, is on Ruby 1.8) and Debian packaging doesn't play well with manually upgrading Ruby.  I've thought about pushing for migration to a RVM-based management system, but we're not there yet.